# Request `_items` only using python-eve API to a MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, api, response, eve

I am using an [python-eve](http://python-eve.org/index.html)-API (short called `eve`) to access a MongoDB. After inserting some sample data I am using [Chrome's Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to test the API.

Since eve provides additional information besides the requested data and [HATEOAS directives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) as explained in the [docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) I just wondered about how to request the `_items`-dictionary only (call it `dictionary` if speaking in terms of Python and `object` if speaking in terms of JSON or JavaScript).

So the sample request `http://127.0.0.1:5000/packagings/` gives the response shown below from which I am only interested in the data contained in the `_items`-dictionary/-object.

For sure, I can extract the desired data after receiving and storing the full response.
However, is there a way to only request the data I am interested in in order to reduce additional data extraction resp. data handling once the data are received?

```
{
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "packagings",
            "title": "packagings"
        },
        "parent": {
            "href": "/",
            "title": "home"
        }
    },
    "_meta": {
        "max_results": 25,
        "page": 1,
        "total": 1
    },
    "_items": [
        {
            "diameter_dk": 0.0144,
            "_created": "Tue, 17 Nov 2015 21:15:37 GMT",
            "factor_fa": 2.1,
            "_id": "564b98f955c40f29843128df",
            "free_volume": 0.89,
            "title": "raschigring10x10x0.5",
            "_updated": "Tue, 17 Nov 2015 21:15:37 GMT",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "packagings/564b98f955c40f29843128df",
                    "title": "Packaging"
                }
            },
            "specific_weight": 920,
            "title_hr": "Raschig-Ring 10x10x0.5",
            "specific_surface": 500,
            "specific_number": 770000,
            "_etag": "bcb4080b61028405babcd960196d27208c3eabd3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable HATEOAS by setting `HATEOAS = False` in your configuration settings. That should greatly reduce the payload, making it more suitable for your use case.

EDIT: You can also choose to transform the response payload by hooking a callback function to the `on_fetched_resource` event.

```
from eve import Eve

def on_fetched_resource(resource, response):
    del(response['_links'])
    del(response['_meta'])

    # would result in an empty JSON document
    # del(response['_items'])

app = Eve()
app.on_fetched_resource += on_fetched_resource

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Since the response is a dict (it's JSON after all), you would still need to provide a key for the documents array.

Comment: As you said, this reduces the payload greatly by not pushing the `_links` object to the array. However, isn't there a way just to receive the desired data object?

Comment: Edited after your comment

Comment: @NicolaIarocci how to show just the _items object? like if i wanna show persons object direct from mongodb [{'firstname':'Sunny','lastname':'hashmi' }]. Without _items key as well.

Comment: @AHashmi that would call for a new question. Anyway: if you disable HATEOAS, you will only get a list of documents with the response.

Comment: @NicolaIarocci HATEOS disable doesn't response with array, I've created new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160423/request-array-of-json-documents-disable-item-reference-from-mongodb-using-pyth

Comment: Right, disabling HATEOAS will work for document endpoints, not for resource endpoint.

Comment: @NicolaIarocci how can we `on_fetched_resource` at document level? 

I tried:

    `def on_fetched_resource(item, response):
        del(response['_items'])`

but no luck!

PS: I already have `'hateoas' : False`

Comment: @haytham you have the documents in `response['_items']`. You could loop through them `for doc in response['_items']` and do whatever you want with them. For instance, I wanted to remove the `_id` fields from them and I could not do it with `projection:{_id:0}` so I just removed like that, one by one (they are just a few per request anyway)