# Request array of json documents (disable item reference) from MongoDB using python eve

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, flask, eve

Using Python eve framework, Is there any way to get response shown in first json type which is array of objects like shown in example?. I have tried to disable HATEOAS like it says [here](http://python-eve.org/features.html#disabling-hateoas). Some View Applications use direct fetching on model and collections based on it, such as [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) NodeJS data handler.

```
 [
  {
    "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc763",
    "question": "1",
    "uk": "I heard a bloke on the train say that tomorrow's trains will be delayed.",
    "us": "I heard a guy on the train say that tomorrow's trains will be delayed."
  },
  {
    "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc764",
    "question": "2",
    "uk": "Tom went outside for a fag. I think he smokes too much!",
    "us": "Tom went outside for a cigarette. I think he smokes too much!"
  }
]
```

Instead of returning the JSON object with _items key like it shows:

```
{
  "_items":[
            {
              "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc763",
              "question": "1",
              "uk": "I heard a bloke on the train",
              "us": "I heard a guy on the train"
            },
            {
              "_id": "526c0e21977a67d6966dc764",
              "question": "2",
              "uk": "Tom went outside for a fag. I think he smokes too much!",
              "us": "Tom went outside for a cigarette. I think he smokes too much!"
            }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, as the response payload is built as a dictionary in which several keys might appear (pagination data, HATOEAS links, and actual documents).

In theory we could add a new configuration option which would switch to a list-formatted (and simplified) layout. Should consider all the consequences though, so no promises, but consider opening a ticket.

Comment: where is on_fetched_item coming from? https://github.com/talkpython/eve-building-restful-mongodb-backed-apis-course/blob/059c699b94ff41305d51a53a8ddb7fcba9881075/code/app.py#L17

Comment: I have the same problem because no [react-admin data provider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html) understands the dictionary structure. I tried to manipulate the database response using the `on_fetch_handler`. However I cannot unpack the dictionary key `_items` into a list because the callback does not have return parameters and Python does not support replacing the dictionary parameter by a list within a function. I ended up changing the functions `_perform_aggregation` and `_perform_find` in get.py so `response` is a list.